# Python efficiency for list comparison on numbers >= 10,000

Tags: python

I've been trying to complete a problem from one of the most recent ACM programming challenges post competition, and have been running into a snag. The problem states

> Your team has been retained by the director of a competition who supervises a panel of judges. The competition asks the judges to assign integer scores to competitors – the higher the score, the better. Although the event has standards for what score values mean, each judge is likely to interpret those standards differently. A score of 100, say, may mean different things to different judges.
>
> The director's main objective is to determine which competitors should receive prizes for the top positions. Although absolute scores may differ from judge to judge, the director realizes that relative rankings provide the needed information – if two judges rank the same competitors first, second, third, ... then they agree on who should receive the prizes.
>
> Your team is to write a program to assist the director by comparing the scores of pairs of judges. The program is to read two lists of integer scores in competitor order and determine the highest ranking place (first place being highest) at which the judges disagree.
>
> Input to your program will be a series of score list pairs. Each pair begins with a single integer giving the number of competitors N, 1 < N < 1,000,000. The next N integers are the scores from the first judge in competitor order. These are followed by the second judge's scores – N more integers, also in competitor order. Scores are in the range 0 to 100,000,000 inclusive. Judges are not allowed to give ties, so each judge’s scores will be unique. Values are separated from each other by one or more spaces and/or newlines. The last score list pair is followed by the end-of-file indicator.

There were example test cases which cover N = 4, and N = 8

> 4
>
> 3 8 6 2
>
> 15 37 17 3
>
> 8
>
> 80 60 40 20 10 30 50 70
>
> 160 100 120 80 20 60 90 135

And the Expected Output:
For each score pair, print a line with the integer representing the highest-ranking place at which the judges do not agree. If the judges agree on every place, print a line containing only the word "agree". Use the format below: "Case", one space, the case number, a colon and one space, and the answer for that case with no trailing spaces.

> Case 1: agree
>
> Case 2: 3

My Code is as follows:

```
import sys

def calculate(competitors, scores1, scores2):
    scores1sort = sorted(scores1, reverse = True)
    scores2sort = sorted(scores2, reverse = True)

    for x in range(len(scores1)) :
        indexed1 = scores1.index(scores1sort[x])
        #print ('place: ', x+1, 'Position: ',indexed1+1)
    #iterating over the entire length  of the sorted lists multiple times takes too long
        indexed2 = scores2.index(scores2sort[x])
        #print ('place: ', x+1, 'Position: ',indexed2+1)
        if indexed2 != indexed1 :
            print ( "Case",  str(case) + ":", x+1)
            return

    #run both fors at the same time, compare indexed of scores1 to index of scores2
    #if the position(indexed + 1) doesnt match between the two, print the place(x+1) of the disparity


    #if match:
        #print ("Case " + case +": " + "agree"
    #else: print (Case " + case + ": " + index of disagreement

    print ("Case", str(case) + ":" , "agree")



    scores1 = [];
    scores2 = [];
    case = 1;
    state = 0;
    # 0 indicates number of competitors
    # 1 indicates judge 1
    # 2 indicates judge 2
    #for line in sys.stdin:
    for line in test.split("\n"):
        line = line.strip().split()
        if not line:
            continue

    if state == 0:
        #if empty line, error
        competitors = int(line[0])
        state = 1;

    else:
        for y in line:
            if state == 1:
                scores1.append(int(y))
                if len(scores1) >= competitors:
                    state = 2;
            elif state == 2:
                scores2.append(int(y))
                if len(scores2) >= competitors:
                    state = 0;
                    #print (competitors, score1, scores2)
                    calculate(competitors, scores1, scores2);
                    case += 1;
```

My code is currently run using a text file containing test input from the programming contest that was left for us, which includes small test values, but also includes a set of values with 10,000 competitors.

I have no doubt that the code could complete if given enough time, but the programming challenge guidelines specified that the code had to run in a window of time shorter than the current runtime.

As such I'd like to ask for any tips anyone might have on how to optimize my code for faster execution.

Comment: Tips or actual code?

Comment: either one or both at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your program is running in quadratic time, so as N gets bigger running time will increase dramatically. You have to get the work done in your inner loop down well below O(n) to handle the larger datasets.

Also, simply sorting the inputs at the start is not helping you because you lose the mapping between associated entries in the two arrays.

How about something like this:

```
def calculate(N, scores1, scores2):
    ranked1 = sorted(enumerate(scores1),key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    ranked2 = sorted(enumerate(scores2),key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    ...
```

Now you have two arrays, sorted from Highest ranking to lowest for a cost of O(n log n) and you can just search for the case where ranked1[i][0] != ranked2[i][0] which is O(n) at worst.

So, the overall running time is O(n + n log n) worst case

Comment: I prefer using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for the key function.  You can name it like ```score = operator.itemgetter(1)``` and the key becomes descriptive: ```key = score```.

Answer (score 1):

Providing sample input will help a bit.
At this point, seems that you are loosing time at index method call and memory alloc in range(in case of running at py2).
Try using *enumerate* to avoid indexing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - OP's requirement was to provide tips, this fulfills that requirement.

Comment: Guys, don't make mountain out of molehill )
I lack reputation to comment question directly, that's the only reason writing this tips as dedicated answer, which is still helpfull a bit, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `list.index()` function use binary search, as the lists will be sorted. `list.index` internally performs linear search, at least in CPython, source code [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/listobject.c#l2276).

Turning that `O(n)` search to `O(log n)` should cut enough time for it to pass.

Comment: Yes. The two calls to sorted() instantly make this at least O(n log n) but the linear work inside the main loop bump the overall algorithm up to O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, using enumerate helps, comments inline:

```
import operator
def foo(one, two):
    index = operator.itemgetter(0)
    score = operator.itemgetter(1)
    # Use enumerate to create a list of (index, score) tuples
    one = list(enumerate(one))
    two = list(enumerate(two))

    # sort the tuple lists on item one using operator.itemgetter
    one.sort(key = score, reverse = True)
    two.sort(key = score, reverse = True)

    # are the indices in the same order?
    for n, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(one, two)):
        # if not find return the rank
        if index(a) != index(b):
            return n + 1
    # yes!
    return 'agree'



one = [3, 8, 6, 2]
two = [15, 37, 17, 3]
print foo(one, two)    # agree
one = [80, 60, 40, 20, 10, 30, 50, 70]
two = [160, 100, 120, 80, 20, 60, 90, 135]
print foo(one, two)    # 3
```